# Differences between SET var = 'abc' and SET GLOBAL var = 'abc'?

Tags: mysql

For example:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 100000;
SET max_allowed_packet = 100000;
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SET GLOBAL` affects the entire server.  `SET` only affects the current session.

For global settings to persist they need to be put in your `my.cnf` file as well.

Comment: affects the MySQL server until that process is restarted (which may not be because of a reboot).